# C++ build on 2010 and running on machine installed 2012 application crash. Any clue

Tags: visual-c++

We have application build on VS2010. But on one machine where VS2012 Update pack 3 is installed, application crashed. Application build on C++ ATL/COM. While running application visual studio changing making any sense??

Comment: Debug the application, learn why it crashed. It might turn out there's some undefined behavior in your code.

Comment: It is not code issue... VS matter if runing application

Comment: Just because the code seemingly work when compiled with one compiler and not with another doesn't mean it has to be the compilers fault. Undefined behaviors that seems to work have a tendency to break when compiled with another compiler, even a different version of the same compiler. Before you accuse the compiler you ***really*** need to make sure, 100%, that it's not something in your code. Have you even *tried* to run in a debugger to catch the crash in action? Where does it happen in ***your*** code?